# not able to write onto a file

Tags: java, java-7, java-io

I have written this code to read from a table and write onto a file, but I am unable to write to a file. The file gets created, but its empty. I don't have a mysql problem tried to insert comments and debug. Code compiles fine, but has a problem in creating a file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class tabletocsv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the table name");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String table = input.next();
        System.out.println("enter number of columns");
        int columns = input.nextInt();
        createcsv(table, columns);
        System.out.print(" csv created");
        displaycsv(table, columns);
    }

    static void displaycsv(String table, int count) {
        Scanner file123;
        try {
            file123 = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Tannishk/Documents/csv/" + table + ".csv"));
            //System.out.printf("reading");
            while (file123.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("going inside");
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    String a = file123.next();
                    System.out.print(a + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tabletocsv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    static void createcsv(String table, int count) {
        Formatter x;
        Connection connection;
        Statement st;
        try {
            x = new Formatter("/Users/Tannishk/Documents/csv/" + table + ".csv");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "root", "password");
            st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from " + table + ";");
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    String a = rs.getString(i);
                    x.format("%s ", a);
                    // System.out.print(a);
                }
                x.format("\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. does the table has any rows? 2. are you getting any exception while creating the file? your catch block is empty so you would not know what the exception is...

Answer (score 2):

Try flushing and closing the formatter

Comment: Thanks man it worked . But i still did't understand the reason why it was not working in the first place ?

Comment: Without flushing the formatter the underlying buffer was not flushed and bytes were not written to the file

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to flush the file.

```
static void createcsv(String table,int count)
{
    Formatter x = null;
    Connection connection;
    Statement st;
    try{

        x = new Formatter("/Users/Tannishk/Documents/csv/"+table+".csv");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","root","password");
        st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select * from "+table+";");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
            {
                String a = rs.getString(i);
                x.format("%s ",a);
                // System.out.print(a);
            }
            x.format("\n");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {

        try {
            x.flush();
            x.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Try this ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the output stream that you're using to write to the file. For example if you're using a FileWriter object named **fout** to write to the file, you'll have to do **fout.close()** to actually have anything written to the file as otherwise it would just be in memory.